# How to abort Tomcat startup upon exception in ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a class implementing `ServletContextListener` that loads some resources upon startup.

Those resources are critical to the application in a way that I would like to fail the whole startup when some bad event happens in my logic.

Is there any command I can execute from inside the `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` method to stop and fail the whole Tomcat startup?

Comment: Did someone find any other way than System.exit(1)?

Comment: @Bastien, use SpringBoot

Comment: @Leo Irrelevant. A correct answer to the question would be an explanation of how SpringBoot manage this issue.

Comment: @Bastien, I don't think a comment is a good place to elaborate on that. I mentioned springboot just to keep it short. The solution is actually the fact of having a standalone webapp using embedded web container. See my answer below.

Comment: @Leo I did but you are just offering a workaround, not addressing the issue at hand.

Comment: I don't think it is a workaround. From my point of view, using `System.exit()` is *the*  workaround. After all, aborting Tomcat startup shouldn't be done, unless you're writing the only app ever deployed. However, the best way to ensure it's only one app per tomcat is to have an embedded one. I just think this is the proper way to do things. Look at this article: http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/application-servers-sort-of-dead/

Comment: @Leo Interesting, this makes a lot of sense if you have a stand alone app I agree. In that case, I would use an embedded server like you suggested. But still, the original issue remains even if the fix is of little use. Point is, there is no way to exit Tomcat on servlet failure, which is bothering.

Comment: @Bastien that's right. And, in the other hand, if you have more applications on the same tomcat, then tomcat startup should not be killed because of one application. So, again, we're back to the original point.

Answer (score 12):

Try specifying:

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE=true
```

in your `java` runtime options, quoting [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html):

> If true, the server will exit if an exception happens during the server initialization phase.
>
> If not specified, the default value of false will be used.

UPDATE:

If you want to do this by code, will `System.exit()` work?

```
public class FailFastListener implements ServletContextListener {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FailFastListener.class);
    
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        try {
            //initialization
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Sooo bad, shutting down", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }
}
```

You can use [decorator](/questions/tagged/decorator) pattern to wrap existing listeners without cluttering them. Not sure how will Tomcat react thou...

Comment: Thanks, that almost solves my problem, but... I am looking to do it by code execution. If impossible - I will use the runtime opt.

Comment: Yep :) the magical System.exit(1) :) I know, I should put me questions in a clearer way... so... Any way to do it through retrieving the Tomcat container? Main reason I afraid that System.exit will not close other events in the life cycle, such as other listeners 'destroy' code... What do you think on that?

Comment: System.exit() will not work when the security manager is enabled.

Comment: Did someone find any other way than System.exit(1)? -Dorg.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE=true will not work in this case since an exception in a contextInitialized method is not considered a server failure, just a servlet failure.

Comment: Do not use System.exit. It's listed as bad practice in CWE knowledge base:
CWE-382: J2EE Bad Practices: Use of System.exit() http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/382.html

Comment: @L.Holanda it's bad practice to call it from Servlet doPost/doGet. It's perfectly OK to call it from `ServletContextListener`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop Tomcat because your webapp failed to deploy, I assume you don't have other apps deployed to tomcat. In that case, why don't you build this app as a standalone webapp with embedded Tomcat/Jetty? This way, as long as your webapp does not start properly, the embedded server will shutdown too.

To me, it looks like you're focused on `ServletContextListener` to tackle a problem that is not what `ServletContextListener` is meant for.

Do not use `System.exit()` because it will kill the server that might be running other deployed apps. If it's ok because you know there will never be other apps (and you don't want to), then make a standalone webapp. This bad practice is listed in CWE as a potential weakness: [CWE-382](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/382.html)

Just a hint: spring boot facilitates the effort of building a standalone webapp with embedded server. See this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Good article explaining why this is probably what you're looking for: http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/application-servers-sort-of-dead/

Comment: I upvoted you as you are generally correct however Tomcat is sort of a special case because embedded tomcat isn't always truly embedded... that is multiple classloaders are still used. For example the Tomcat Maven plugin will turn a single WAR into an executable JAR **but** it actually is running very similar to normal Tomcat. Spring Boot doesn't do this as it is the parent and Tomcat runs in the same classloader. There is actually a benefit of having multiple classloaders (the tomcat maven plugin way) as you can avoid issues with Tomcats jars (such as its choice in logging).