# Abort Tomcat start-up

Tags: java, tomcat

Specifically, I want Tomcat to abort start-up when my web app can't initialize (due to a configuration error).

1. I'm tried to use the Tomcat shutdown port.  That's not ready when my web app is starting up.
2. -Dorg.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE=true, doesn't work.  Tomcat starts up just fine.
3. Throw an uncaught Exception.  I've tried throwing an exception.  Tomcat still initializes correctly but my web app is in a non-functional state.
4. Use the Tomcat JMX API.  None of the shutdown methods will cause Tomcat to shut down.

So far, the only other option I've got is `System.exit(-1)`.  That does work, but I'm  concerned that doing that to Tomcat will cause problems.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13932746/422353?

Comment: No, it's not a dupe.  My app doesn't implement ServletContextListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat is designed to be resilient against badly written applications that don't start up.

org.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE is for stopping Tomcat if one of Tomcat's components, such as one of the connectors, doesn't start (e.g. because the port is in use).

System.exit() is ugly but it will work and it is safe as far as Tomcat is concerned (as for that matter is kill -9). It is applications that may not like this rather brutal approach to shutdown.

There is a Tomcat specific way to do this more cleanly. Add a custom LifecycleListener to the Server component and have it respond to AFTER_START_EVENT. Have the listener navigate the Container hierarchy from the Server to the Contexts [Server->Service(s)->Engine-Host(s)->Context(s)] and check that each context is in the state STARTED. If not, call stop() and then destroy() on the Server.

Comment: that sounds like it just might be what I'm looking for!

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @sp00m implementation based on instructions given in this answer: https://gist.github.com/xkr47/9088839 - worked fine both for "address already in use" and for generic web app startup failure

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of the listener which aborts the Tomcat startup, as mentioned by Mark Thomas. `StrictStateCheckListener` is an after-start server listener. It checks the state of all [Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Container.html), including engine, host, and context. The server start-up will be aborted if there's any component failed to start (state different from `STARTED`).

```
package com.example.lifecycle;

import java.util.logging.*;
import org.apache.catalina.*;

public class StrictStateCheckListener implements LifecycleListener {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StrictStateCheckListener.class.getName());

  private boolean hasFailures;

  private String containerState;

  @Override
  public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
    String type = event.getType();
    Lifecycle lifecycle = event.getLifecycle();

    if (lifecycle instanceof Server && type.equals(Lifecycle.AFTER_START_EVENT)) {
      Server server = (Server) lifecycle;
      hasFailures = false;

      // Check status of each container
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Status:").append(System.lineSeparator());
      for (Service service : server.findServices()) {
        checkState(service.getContainer(), sb, "");
      }
      if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.INFO)) {
        LOGGER.info(sb.toString());
      }
      if (hasFailures) {
        /*
         * The server will not be stopped by this listener. Indeed,
         * an exception is raised to trigger shutdown hook. See:
         * `org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina`.
         */
        throw new IllegalStateException(containerState);
      }
    }
  }

  private void checkState(Container container, StringBuilder report, String indent) {
    if (!hasFailures && container.getState() != LifecycleState.STARTED) {
      hasFailures = true;
      containerState = stateOf(container);
    }
    report.append(indent).append(stateOf(container));
    for (Container child : container.findChildren()) {
      checkState(child, report, indent + "  ");
    }
  }

  private String stateOf(Container container) {
    String className = container.getClass().getSimpleName();
    String stateName = container.getStateName();
    return String.format("%s[%s]: %s%n", className, container.getName(), stateName);
  }
}
```

Register this listener to your server component via `server.xml`:

```
<Server>
  ...
  <Listener className="com.example.lifecycle.StrictStateCheckListener" />
  ...
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point No 1
Do you mean when uninitialized state exception is thrown from application  you are calling tomcat shutdown.bat file.Have you tried to call  shutdown.bat file from your program.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I'm going a bit further here thinking out of the box to solution you are seeking. It looks like your requirement is to stop tomcat when your webapp fails to initialize. This is a bit different than "abort Tomcat start-up". Tomcat itself is already started and will start to deploy your webapp right after it started up. Based on your requirement, I assume that you don't have any other webapp. If that's the case, why don't you just use Spring Boot? Spring boot provides a way to deploy self contained web application. In this case, if initialization fails, application will not start.